# Eventlistner on Checkbox should give user a prompt

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I have a checkbox on the webpage and I want that when the check box is ticked a prompt should come with a 'message and YES\NO button'. Clicking YES should take the user to the next website and clicking NO just close the prompt.

How can this be done using Javascript.How will the program know if the checkbox is yicked or not? I read using addeventlistner but i dont know how to use it. Can someone share an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addEventListener` to bind event

```
document.getElementById('testcb').addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        if (confirm('Really Take me to new loaction?')) {
            alert("Take me to new loaction");
            //window.location.href = newURL;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zk6Gc/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library, like jQuery, and you could do somtehing like this

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="testcb" id="testcb" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#testcb').click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
           if (confirm('Really?'))
               window.location.href = newURL;
        }
    });
});
```

Careful with `addEventListener` : it will not work with IE 8 and below, and '`change`' event is buggy in the same browser (IE8-) (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add a JavaScript function on check box event ,

```
HTML
<input id="chk" onclick="doSomething()"  type="checkbox">


javascript function : 


function doSomething()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("chk").checked;
  if (x)
  { var conf = confirm("checkbox is checked, proceed ?");
   if (conf == true) {
   window.location = "http://www.google.com";
  }
 }
}
```

Don't forget to add reference of jQuery (you can add from googleAPI)